# Prove or Disprove $I=\{a_0x^0+\dots +a_nx^n:a_0+\dots+a_n=0\}$ is a sub ring of field F[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Prove or Disprove  $I=\{a_0x^0+\dots +a_nx^n:a_0+\dots+a_n=0\}$ is subring of field F[x]

---

We need to show it is a subring that is

- closed addition
- closed multiplication **(struggling)**
- $\exists $ neutral additive identity
- $\exists $ additive inverse

*Closed addition*

Suppose $f(x),g(x) \in I$ where 
    $$f(x)=a_0x^0+\dots +a_nx^n \text{ s.t } a_0+\dots+a_n=0$$
    $$g(x)=b_0x^0+\dots +b_nx^n \text{ s.t. } b_0+\dots+b_n=0$$
Now, we need to add them and chech that they $h(x)=g(x)+f(x) \in I$

So, $$ h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=(a_0+b_0)x^0+\dots +(a_b+b_n)x^n$$
where $a_0+\dots a_n=0$ and $b_0+\dots b_n=0$. So,
$$0=0+0=(a_0+\dots a_n)+(b_0+\dots b_n)=(a_0+b_0)+\dots+(a_n+b_n) $$ 
So the coeffinets of h(x) add to zero.

*Closed multiplication (struggling at this point)*
*Existence of $0_{F{x}}$*

$0_{F[x]}=0x^0+\dots+0x^n $. It is clear that $0=0+\dots+0$

$Existence of additive inverses$

Now we know that F[x] is a field so there are additive inverses for its constants.where
$$f(x)-f(x)=(a_0-a_0)x^0+\dots+(a_n-a_n)x^n=0_F$$
Now,$ a_0+\dots+a_n=0$ so,$$0=(-1)(0)=-1(a_0+\dots+a_n)=-a_0\dots-a_n$$ So the coefficients of $-f(x)$ add up to zero so $-f(x)\in I $

---

could use some help to show that it is closed under multiplication And  to show that the coefficients add up to 0.

Comment: You haven't specified whether $n$ is fixed, or allowed to vary.

Comment: $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: This cannot be a subring since $1 \notin I$. Moreover, it is not clear why you say that $F[x]$ is a field.

Comment: @crostful Rings  do not need  to have multiplicative identity. for example $Q[x]$ is a field and the set of $\{ 2k:k\in Z\}$ is a subring of $Q[x]$ (wrote it by hand and i think it is true ) but $1\notin \{ 2k:k \in Z\}$ since $1/2 \notin Z$

Comment: 1: $Q[x]$ is NOT  a field. 2: by definition if you have a ring $R$ with unity $1_R$, then every subring must contain the element $1_R$.

Comment: @crostulI meant $Q$. $Q$ is a field it says so on the book. pg 45 hungerford. I'll take your word  about $Q[x]$. closed addition $2k_1+2k_2=2(k_1+k_2)=2k_3$ s.t. $k_3 \in  Z$. $2k1*2k_2=2(k_1*2*k_2)$ where $k_1*2*k_2 \in Z$. $0=0*2$ additive inverse conseder any $2k_1$ $\exists -k_1\in Z$ where $2k_1+2(-k_1)=2(k_1-k_1)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two elements of $I$, say $u=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ and $v=b_0+b_1x+...+b_mx^m$, then their product is

$uv=(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)(b_0+b_1x+...+b_mx^m)=c_0+c_1x+...+c_{m+n}x^{m+n}$.

Then, plugging $x=1$ we have:

$c_0+c_1+...+c_{m+n}=(a_0+a_1+...+a_n)(b_0+b_1+...+b_m)=0$ since sum of $a_j$'s and $b_j$'s is zero by initial assumption.

Hence $uv\in I.$

Comment: Was thinking to go into some ugly summation notation for multiplication and show that that it adds to zero which seems like a nightmare. This is so elegant can't belief I did not see it.