# Prove I=$\{ a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_n x^n: a_0+\dots+a_n=0 \}$ is a principal ideal of field $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove  I=$\{ a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_n x^n: a_0+\dots+a_n=0 \}$ is a principal ideal of field $F[x]$

---

Def of principal ideal $\exists:g(x) \in F[x]:I\equiv\{g(x)f(x):f(x)\in F[x]\}$

*My attempt*

$I$ contains no constant besides $0$. Some elements are
$$I= \{ 0,1-1x,-1+1x,-a+ax,a-ax^n,1+2x-3x^2+x^3\dots\}$$
The things I am considering are finding that $g(x)$ that generates $I$ if it even exists.

Also, there is a related question that I asked showing [I is a ideal or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569458/prove-or-disprove-i-a-0x0-dots-a-nxna-0-dotsa-n-0-is-a-sub-ring-of).

---

Since $I$ is missing 1 at most I is a commutative ring not a field, not an integral domain.

Comment: If $F$ is any field, the ring $F[x]$ is principal, i.e. all ideals of $F[x]$ are principal. Thus there's really only one thing to prove: $I$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. If $I$ is indeed a principal ideal, then it must be generated by a nonzero element of $I$ of the smallest possible order.
2. We can get $a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=0$ from $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n=0$ by substituting $x=1$.

Note that either one of these can independently lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal $I = \{f:\, f(1) = 0\}\subset F[X]$, and so $I = (X - 1)$.